# Ant Design Timepicker - get input value onKeyUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

How can I get the value of the Timepicker input as it is typed ? Looked into the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/time-picker/#API) and the 2 events are available, onChange and onSelect. Neither of which help solve my need.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a workaround by wrapping the `TimePicker` component in `div` , add `onChange` on that div and get the `TimePicker` input value by `ref` like that:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { TimePicker } from "antd";

const Solution = () => {
  const timeContainerRef = useRef(null);

  const onChange = () => {
    const timeInputValue =
      timeContainerRef.current.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.value;
    console.log(timeInputValue); //typed info
  };
  return (
    <div onChange={onChange} ref={timeContainerRef}>
      <TimePicker />
    </div>
  );
};
```